# Get all form tags with javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any such function to get all form tags?

by form tags I mean all `<input>`, `<select>` etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) the following will make them pink:

```
$("input, select, textarea").css({background: "pink"});
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention jQuery. Had he, @Lachlan's response is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290991/get-all-form-tags-with-javascript-function/2291023#2291023

Answer (score 3):

You could use jquery:

```
$(':input')
```

Otherwise, given the id of the form, all of its fields are given by

```
var formid = "foo";
var myform = document.getElementById( formid )
if (myform != null) {
    // myform.elements is an array of the fields
}
```

And if you just wanted to find all the select elements in the page, use getElementsByTagName()

```
var all_selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select')
```

Comment: "all form tags" meaning <input>, <select> and <textarea>

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = getElementsByTagName("input")
    .splice(getElementsByTagName("select"));

// splice to your hearts content
```

Answer (score 0):

A framework is overkill for this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")
document.getElementsByTagName("select")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFormElements() {
  var ary = [];
  // use the full list of supported form elements below if this is not exhaustive
  var elementNames = ['input','select','textarea','button']; 
  for (var i=0; i < elementNames.length; i++) {
    ary.concat(document.getElementsByTagName(elementNames[i]));
  }
  return ary;
}
```